# Why there are many wedding at night?

Tags: marriage, muhurta

What is actually a reason behind having a wedding at late night? Is it because of better muhurta? or is there any historical or cultural reason or it is based on some scriptural advice?

Please do not close this, I am looking for some reasons for this "time slot selection"

Comment: Historical reasons. And this is more common in North. This was done to evade the islamic invaders who would abduct the bride-to-be. Hence if you notice that weddings in South , where the menace of invaders was relatively less, weddings are during day time

Comment: All Bengali weddings, without exception, always take place at night. The reason is what @Carmensandiego mentioned.

Comment: @Carmensandiego - history is not the only reason. chandramana panchanga (lunar calendar) is the main reason. Andhra weddings happen at night too.

Comment: @mar - yes, muhurta can be at night. And weddings did take place at night in South.

Comment: Brahma muhurta marriages

Comment: @sbharti - brahma muhurta is early morning 4.30-6

Comment: Lot of myths shared in this thread. See 1) Mrg happens in night even in south https://mobile.twitter.com/BharadwajSpeaks/status/1466476348524875785 and 2) Day mrg is due to different calender https://mobile.twitter.com/BharadwajSpeaks/status/1466487029831802897 and finally 3) Even kings married in night, again due to muhurta not fear https://mobile.twitter.com/BharadwajSpeaks/status/1466501502147522562 . We should stick to scriptures in answers.

Comment: Yes thats what I am looking for, scriptural reference for such thing

Comment: @sbharti - read the question. It is asking "why many took place at night". It is not suggesting that "only took place at night". There is historical basis for it. And history of Hinduism happens to be in scope in HSE

Comment: @Carmensandiego as stated above, your 1st comment is untrue and only based on conjectures (pls provide scriptural basis otherwise). No such practice developed due to islamic invaders. It is based on jyotish calenders and varies because different calenders are used.

Comment: @sbharti - kindly comprehend what you are saying. How do you expect scriptures to contain incidents of Islamic invaders. The point is quite straightforward. As per Jyotish calendars , weddings muhurta is both mornings and evenings. But due to invaders ppl in North stuck to night

Answer (score -1):

Earlier, marriages used to be in the day like marriage of Lord Ram and Mata Sita, or the Pandavas to Draupadi.

This custom started after the Turks invaded Bharat and used to attack weddings in the day commit horrific crimes against our mothers and sisters. Hence, to hide from them this ritual started and is still being continued.

Comment: Pls share references to support your answer